# Create Data Source from programmatically retrieved data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, data-binding

I have a RESTful web service that provides me with JSON data that I can retrieve and deserialize into a `DataTable` using `Json.NET` and a custom conversion method.

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
List<JobApplication> ja = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JobApplication>>(json);
```

I've previously bound controls to a data source inside the project using the IDE/designer in Visual Studio, but in those situations the data has been retrieved from a database using the designer, resulting in auto-generated data sources that I can bind to.

Right now, all I can do is set the data source of the main `DataGridView` to my `DataTable` object as below, but that will display all columns and I'd like to set the properties of them in the designer of the `DataGridView`.

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I want to bind other controls to the same data, that is changed when the row selection is changed. I also want to specify what columns are to be displayed in the `DataGridView`.

Am I left to do this programmatically or are there any way I can make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

For specifying the columns to show, I usually do something like this:

```
var myCollection = from d in db.myTable
              select new
              {
                 col1 = d.col,
                 col2 = d.anotherCol,
                 col3 = d.andAnotherCol
              };

 myGrid.DataSource = myCollection;
 myGrid.DataBind();
```